# c# - Public Class with index accessor

Tags: c#, class, indexing

I want to create a global accessible struct/class (in C#) to access my stock prices from the callback handler.

I know only C and it's easy there

Example in C

```
 struct _Sample
 { 
    int SomeValue; 
 };
 struct _Sample Sample[10];
```

That's what I have so far in C# after 2 hours of trying.

```
public static class GlobalVar
{
    private static double _StockPrice;

    public static double SetStockPrice
    {
        set
        {
                _StockPrice = value;
        }
    }

    public static double GetStockPrice
    {
        get
        {
                return _StockPrice;
        }
     }
}
```

The above example can be used as `GlobalVar.SetStockPrice = 10.254;` I know I have to use the `<List>` to make _StockPrice available as an array, but all my attempts to compile a working solution failed.

I would like to access it as `GlobalVar[1].SetStockPrice = 1.0;` and `GlobalVar[1].SetStockPrice = 1.0;`

I have to use C# because the SDK I'm using is only available in C#.

Comment: use an array instead of a class.

Comment: I'd think that you want to use SetStockPrice as a collection rather than a single object.

Comment: You can't do it in C# up to 5.0. Even 6.0 only allow "global" method calls, not properties - so you can't have global indexer called (you can get syntax you wanted with making reference to singleton object local to your class)...

Answer (score 1):

You would have to add a StockPrice class and keep an internal dictionary inside of GlobalVar to make this work, but you could use this:

```
public StockPrice this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        StockPrice stockPrice = null;

        if (index > -1)
        {
            InternalDictionary.TryGetValue(index, out stockPrice);
        }
        return stockPrice;
    }
}
```

Then you can do `GlobalVar[index]` to get a certain StockPrice object from that internal dictionary of `GlobalVar`.

Also note that this will not work on a static class because static indexers are not allowed in C#. You might want to change your class to be a singleton instead of a static.

**EDIT:** A more complete example (still needs work though) with a singleton implementation:

```
public class GlobalVars
{
    static StockPrices _stockPrices = new StockPrices();
    public static StockPrices StockPrices 
    {
        get
        {
            return _stockPrices ;
        }
    }
}

public class StockPrices
{
    Dictionary<int, StockPrice> InternalDictionary = new Dictionary<int, StockPrice>();

    public StockPrice this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            StockPrice stockPrice = null;

            if (index > -1)
            {
                InternalDictionary.TryGetValue(index, out stockPrice);
            }
            return stockPrice;
        }
    }

    public void Add(StockPrice stockPrice)
    {
        int index = InternalDictionary.Keys.Max() + 1;
        InternalDictionary.Add(index, stockPrice);
    }
}
```

Then you could call your code like this:

```
GlobalVars.StockPrices[1].DoSomething
```

Answer (score 0):

The C example you gave, is creating an array with 10 instances of the struct.

The equivalent C# code is this:

```
struct _Sample
{ 
  public int SomeValue; 

  public static _Sample[] Sample = new _Sample[10];
};
```

That is not very C#-ish however. Using C# style I would write something like

```
struct Sample
{
  public int SomeValue { get; set; }

  public static Sample[] Values = new Sample[10];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to have the same behaviour like in [c](/questions/tagged/c). Notice that you don't need to make `SetField` and `GetField` using `{ get; set; }` you get this behaviour by default (it's a property).

```
public struct Sample
{
    public double StockPrice { get; set; }
}

public static class GlobalVar
{
    public static Sample[] Samples = new Sample[10];
}
```

And to acces use

```
GlobalVar.Samples[1].StockPrice = 1.0;
```